# What is the most challenging development environment you've ever had to work in and what did you do to get around the limitations?

Tags: debugging, development-environment

By 'challenging development environment' I don't mean you're on a small boat that's rocking up and down and someone is holding a gun to your head. I mean, are the tools at your disposal making the problem difficult?

Development is typically a cycle of code, run, observe the result, repeat. In some environments this is a very quick and painless process, but in others it's very difficult. We end up using little tricks to help us observe the result and run the code faster.

I was thinking of this because I just started using SSIS (an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etl) tool included with SQL Server 2005/8). It's been quite challenging for me to make progress, mainly because there's no guidance on what all the dialogs mean and also because the errors are very cryptic and most of the time don't really tell you what the problem is.

I think the easiest environment I've had to work in was VB6 because there you can edit code while the application is running and it will continue running with your new code! You don't even have to run it again. This can save you a lot of time. Surprisingly, in Netbeans with Java code, you can do the same. It steps out of the method and re-runs the method with the new code.

In SQL Server 2000 when there is an error in a trigger you get no stack trace, which can make it really tricky to locate where the problem occurred since an insert can have a cascading effect and trigger many triggers. In Oracle you get a very nice little stack trace with line numbers so resolving the problem is very easy.

Some of the things that I see really help in locating problems:

1. Good error messages when things go wrong.
2. Providing a stack trace when a problem occurs.
3. Debug environment where you can pause, then output the value of variables and step to follow the execution path.
4. A graphical debug environment that shows the code as it's running.
5. A screen that can show the current values of variables so you can print to them.
6. Ability to turn on debug logging on a production system.

What is the worst you've seen and what can be done to get around these limitations?

EDIT

I really didn't intend for this to be flame bait. I'm really just looking for ideas to improve systems so that if I'm creating something I'll think about these things and not contribute to people's problems. I'm also looking for creative ways around these limitations that I can use if I find myself in this position.

Comment: Tell me a story... You might find http://thedailywtf.com/ helpful...

Comment: This question is too general, and highly subjective.

Comment: You can't have it both ways...is Good error messages or stack trace number 1?

Comment: I don't think I'll ever understand the "subjective and argumentative" thing for community Wikis. If nobody's getting rep, what harm does it do ?

Comment: Voting to re-open, this is a valid question and is CW.

Comment: Hasn't this been asked before?

Comment: Well, if it has, I didn't see where

Comment: @Uri: S&A is bad news for a Q&A site because it promotes partisan discussion rather than collaborative assistance - and it tends to bleed out into the rest of the site. There are other sites to gripe about tools/platforms/coworkers - no reason to bring those here.

Comment: Regardless, this isn't even a real question. If sjbotha doesn't like DailyWTF, then he's free to post his opinions on a blog somewhere.

Comment: Even if it were a question, it's a discussion question.  This site is not suitable for discussions.  Clear, objective answers are the intended result of a question - not subjective stories.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on making modifications to [Magento](http://magentocommerce.com) for a client. There is very little information on how the Magento system is organized. There are hundreds of folders and files, and there are at least a thousand view files. There was little support available from Magento forums, and I suspect the main reason for this lack of information is because the creators of Magento want you to pay them to become a certified Magento developer. Also, at that time last year there was no StackOverflow :)

My first task was to figure out how the database schema worked and which table stored some attributes I was looking for. There are over 300 tables in Magento, and I couldn't find out how the SQL queries were being done. So I had just one option...

- I exported the entire database (300+ tables, and at least 20,000 lines of SQL code) into a .sql file using PhpMyAdmin, and I 'committed' this file into the subversion repositry. Then, I made some changes to the database using the Magento administration panel, and redownloaded the .sql file. Then, I ran a DIFF using TortioseSvn, and scrolled through the 20k+ lines file to find which lines had changed, LOL. As crazy as it sounds, it did work, and I was able to figure out which tables I needed to access.
- My 2nd problem was, because of the crazy directory structure, I had to ftp to about 3 folders at the same time for trivial changes. So I had to keep 3 windows of my ftp program open, switch between them and ftp each time.
- The 3rd problem was figuring out how the url mapping worked and where some of the code I wanted was being stored. Here, by sheer luck, I managed to find the Model class I was looking for.

Mostly by sheer luck and other similar crazy adventures I managed to work my way through and complete the project. Since then, StackOverflow was started and by a helpful answer to [this bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-does-magento-code-work) I was able to finally get enough information about Magento that I can do future projects in a less crazy manner (hopefully).

Comment: Glad I chose Drupal+Ubercart over Magento for my last project then

Comment: Great solution to the database problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try keypunching your card deck in Fortran, complete with IBM JCL (Job Control Language), handing it in at the data center window, coming back the next morning and getting an inch-thick stack of printer paper with the hex dump of your crash, and a list of the charges to your account.

Grows hair on your fingernails.

I guess that was an improvement on the prior method of sitting at the console, toggling switches and reading the lights.

Answer (score 1):

Occam on a 400x transputer network. As there was only one transputer that could output to console debugging was a nightmare. Had to build a test harness on a Sun network.

Answer (score 1):

I took a class once, that was loosely based on [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), except it was taught in Dylan rather than Scheme. Actually, it was in the old Dylan syntax, the prefix one that was based on Scheme. But because there were no interpreters for that old version of Dylan, the professor wrote one. In Java. As an applet. Which meant that it had no access to the filesystem; you had to write all of your code in a separate text editor, and then paste it into the Dylan interpreter. Oh, and it had no debugging facilities, of course. And being a Dylan interpreter written in Java, and this was back in 2000, it was ungodly slow.

Print statement debugging, lots of copying and pasting, and an awful lot of cursing at the interpreter were involved.

Comment: OMG poor guy. That must really have sucked.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the 90's, I was developing applications in Clipper, a compilable dBase-like language. I don't remember if it came with a debugger, we often used a 3rd-party debugger called 'Mr Debug' (really!). Although Clipper was fast, some of our more intensive routines were written in C. If you prayed to the correct gods and uttered the necessary incantations, you could use Microsoft's CodeView  debugger to debug the C code. But usually not for more than a few minutes, as the program usually didn't like to spend much time running with CodeView (usually memory problems).

I had a series of makefile switches that I used to stub out the sections of code that I didn't need to debug at the time. My debugging environment was very sparse so there was as much free memory as possible for the program. I also think I drank a lot more back then...

Comment: Mr.Debug was a great 3rd Party Add-On for Clipper, but I would say that as it was produced by a company I co-founded. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I reverse engineered game copy protections. Because the protections was written in C or C++ they were fairly easy to disassemble and understand what was going on. But in some cases it got hairy when the copy protection took a detour into the kernel to obfuscate what was happening. A few of them also started to use of custom made virtual machines to make the problem less understandable. I spent hours writing hooks and debuggers to be able to trace into them. The environment really offered a competetive and innovative mind. I had everything at my disposal save time. Misstakes caused reboots and very little feedback what went wrong. I realized thinking before acting is often a better solution.

Today I dispise debuggers. If the problem is in code visible to me I find it easiest to use verbose logging. (Sometimes the error is not understanding the interface/environment then debuggers are good.) I have also realized time is of an essance. You need to have a good working environment with possibility to test your code instantly. If you compiler takes 15 sec, your environment takes 20 sec to update or your caches takes 5 minutes to clear find another way to test your code. Progress keeps me motivated and without a good working environment I get bored, angry and frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

The worst in recent memory was developing SSRS reports using Dundas controls. We were doing quite a bit with the grids which required coding. The pain was the bugginess of the controls, and the lack of debugging support.

I never got around the limitations, but just worked through them.

Comment: There seems to be a missing word after "quite".

Answer (score 0):

The last job I had I was a Sitecore Developer.  Bugfixing can be very painful if the bug only occurs on the client's system, and they do not have Visual Studio installed on the system, with the remote debugging off, and the problem only happens on the production server (not the staging server).