# Magento DataFlow Integration and Module Development Resources?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Does anyone have any good resources for developing Magento Modules that integrate with their DataFlow component? I need to build a product/inventory/order synchronization system and am finding it difficult to dive into. I've done quite a bit of digging, but can't seem to find much in terms of documentation, tutorials, examples, etc.

What resources did you other Magento development gurus utilize when learning the platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learning curve on Magento is pretty steep, unfortunately.

There was a recent post on the Magento Blog that should be helpful: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/introduction-to-magento-dataflow/

As for general Magento learning, Alan Storm has some excellent articles that lay bear the architecture:
[alanstorm.com/category/magento](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) 
as well a good post here on Stack Overflow:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-does-magento-code-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-does-magento-code-work)

On top of this post is an ERD of the database structure:
[www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7359/#top](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/7359/#top)
and over here is a diagram of the request flow:
[www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/magento-architecture](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/magento-architecture)

Specific questions can sometimes be found on the Magento forums, and the the basic interfaces can be found in the docs at [docs.magentocommerce.com](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/).

Hope this is helpful.  Happy Trails!