# magento example module

Tags: magento

I'm reading through chapter 4 of the magento developers guide which explains how to build a shipping module I've built the config.xml put it in the proper place, put the MagentoBook_ShippingModule.xml file  where it needs to go then it tells me I can configure it in the admin panel but it doesn't show up do I need to reboot the server or something for it to take effect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I found the answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-does-magento-code-work) you have to refresh magento's cache

Comment: In development, you may even want to disable the cache to prevent this common issue.