# Magento - Clean custom Account/Registration Fields

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.magento.cc/custom-accountregistration-fields.html) to add fields in the registration form of a customer under Magento, I succeed to run the example, but I know that It is not clean, for upates later...

What' the best way to rewrite all the files used in the tutorial, in a clean way :

- app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/customer/form/register.phtml
- app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/customer/form/edit.phtml
- app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Entity/Setup.php
- app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml
- app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your own module. **Never edit files in `app/code/core/` folder**. If you want to add functionality to Magento, you need to **rewrite** the base classes.

Alan Storm has good tutorials to follow:

[How to create a simple 'Hello World' module in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-does-magento-code-work/588683#588683)

To rewrite a controller (`AccountController` in your case), and after you create you own module, you can follow [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) tutorial.

### Configure the Layout

In your `app/code/local/MyCompany/Module/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mydesign>
                    <file>myfile.xml</file>
                </mydesign>
            </updates>
        </layout>
(...)
```

Then you could update your layout in `app/design/frontend/default/mydesign/layout/myfile.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the good links joksnet, I have created a module with "module creator", can I now modify the xml file located in"\app\design\frontend\my_company\default\layout\customer.xml" to load my custom phtml files ?

Comment: I don't known how "module creator" works. But check the configuration for your layout update XML in `app/code/local/MyCompany/Module/etc/config.xml`. As I described in the answer.