# How do you do simple stuff in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

So I've been following tutorials from

http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/07/create-your-first-magento-module.html?showComment=1331751126549#c2304517526193268399

and

[How to create a simple 'Hello World' module in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento)

I have some basic understanding but what I'm really trying to do is just make a text area box that can store information to the database. One is a comment box for the payment information and another is a notes area regarding clients. Any links or tutorials will help, thank you!

Comment: @ignas - Perhaps the learner is the issue? There is simply no excuse for programmers of even moderate ability to fail to learn the framework - besides laziness or aloofness.

Comment: @Ben - I would agree, but ZF is almost like a new programing language even for advanced PHP users. I'm not saying it's not worth it or it's too difficult to learn, but its just too time consuming to get the basic understanding of how to accomplish a simple task with it. Also the docs are really bad compared to other frameworks.

Comment: I completely agree with Ben, being a .NET developer, I've had to overcome learning PHP and the framework...I was able to put a fully working Magento site live after only 5 weeks...including some pretty heavy modifications due to the unique way our business is run. @Panwar22, I'd recommend getting into the code and playing with it...there's nothing like actually getting your hands dirty.

Answer (score 2):

There are heaps of thorough resources, blog posts, and of course Stack Overflow.
Here's a list of my favorites:

- [alanstorm.com](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) - [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4668/alan-storm) is a notorious developer who has contributed a lot to the Magento community. Also, his [Magento Quickies tumblr](http://magento-quickies.tumblr.com/) is sweet.
- [aschroder.com](http://www.aschroder.com/category/magento/) - A Kiwi who must've cloned himself to do all of the things that he's done.
- [www.fabrizio-branca.de](http://www.fabrizio-branca.de/) Fabrizio is another tireless worker in the Magento world, and he shares lots of information about Magento and Typo3 on his blog.
- [inchoo.com](http://inchoo.com) - Inchoo are a Croatian development firm, and they have been deciphering the framework and posting information to all for several years.
- [magebase.com](http://magebase.com/) - A collection of Magento developers who put out posts that can help out quite a bit
- [Magento Knowledgebase](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento) - Magento has a full knowledgebase, and Alan Storm's developers series is a must-read for folks new to the frameowrk
- [Magento U](http://www.magentocommerce.com/training) - Magento recognized that they needed to get more information out there, so you can get the Fundamentals of Magento development course for free or take it in-person
- [Stack Overflow Magento Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento) - One of my favorites!
- [The codebase](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/) - There's no learning without firing up your IDE and stepping through things.

Have fun. Magento is distinct!

Comment: Very nice, several sources I haven't seen yet.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no such thing as 'simple' in Magento. That being said it is a very consistent MVC architected system, allowing for extension and overriding to achieve the system you want.

I have found that one of the best resources for learning Magento development is [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento%20Alan%20Storm).
Another good resource is [Pierre Fay](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5), Pierre's target is creating a Magento Plugin from start to finish, but it gives you a good view of the internals of Magento.

I find new info on Magento development every day, just by googling certain features.

Enjoy!