# Magento: concatenation of two fields while displaying records in admin in my own module

Tags: php

Can anybody help me to get the desired result in custom module of Magento.

I have creating packages and the packages database is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `packages` (
  `packages_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `package_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `package_description` text NOT NULL,
  `package_price` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'days->1, weeks->2, months->3, years->4',
  `time` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`packages_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I want to display the records in my grid as follows:

```
Id    Package Name      Package Description    Package Time   Package Price    Status  
1     Half Yearly       Bla Bla Bla...         12             USD 200          Active
```

Note:- 
I want to display Package Time with time type(like): time, time type

Eg.: 12 Months

Comment: What have you done with the creation of you module? I would suggest looking at other resources for learning how to develop for Magento. This question should give you a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708855/how-do-you-do-simple-stuff-in-magento (Simple concatenation is straightforward with PHP, just use the . between the strings to concatenate.)