# Deleting empty categories in magento

Tags: php, magento, frontend, categories

I want to implement something that would **delete** the empty categories and sub categories if there are no products in them.

There may be 100s of categories.So I don't want to use backend for this.

I am in trouble please help me.

I am referring this link [Hide Empty Categories](http://prattski.com/2011/10/06/magento-module-hide-empty-categories/) but this is only hiding parent categories from navigation bar even if it's sub categories have products in them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to **delete** empty categories...

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('level', array('gteq' => 2))
;

foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
    if ($category->getProductCount() === 0) {
        $category->delete();
    }
}
```

**This will delete the categories - not simply hide them**

---

**EDIT**

To answer the following posted in a comment:

```
"Could you please share a link of some tutorial or weblink.I am weak in creating custom modules".
```

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento)

You would be better just creating a script for this simple task.  [Here is a nice resource](https://robinwinslow.uk/2013/05/29/ease-magento-development-with-bootstrapped-scripts/) to explain how to bootstrap Magento for your script to run.

Comment: Could you please share a link of some tutorial or weblink.I am weak in creating custom modules.

Comment: Could you please tell me how and where to implement this code.

Comment: I am referring this link  "http://prattski.com/2011/10/06/magento-module-hide-empty-categories/"  but this is only hiding parent categories from navigation bar even if it's sub categories have products in them.

Comment: @Muk: If this is one time business, Why you want to create a module ? just create the script file in root and execute then remove it. Make your life lighter.

Comment: @Muk - In my answer there are two links at the bottom: the first is a tutorial on how to create a custom module.  The second will show you how to bootstrap Magento, which you can use to build a script.  Its up to you which method to choose.

Comment: @Drew Hunter: i have experiment your code, Its trying to delete Magento root directory. And throw me the error.

Comment: @muk If I have the category ids .How can I find the subcategories  and product count for that?

Comment: @gowri - i have updated the answer for you.  Simply filter the collection

Comment: @Muk - this is becoming a completely different question.  You would be best addressing your new queries in a new question