# How to show Invoice Creation Date on Magento

Tags: magento, pdf, invoice

Now on magento when I print an Invoice as PDF, it shows "Order date".. we need to replace it with the "Invoice Creation Date".

Can you tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the invoice by

```
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($invoiceIncrementId);
```

and then get the invoice date using

```
$createdDate = $invoice->getCreatedAt();
```

and put $createdDate and modify the below code from

```
$page->drawText(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
                $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium', false
            ),
            35,
            ($top -= 15),
            'UTF-8'
        );
```

To

```
$page->drawText(
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice Creation Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
                $createdDate, 'medium', false
            ),
            35,
            ($top -= 15),
            'UTF-8'
        );
```

**NOTE :-**

If you have multiple invoices for the same order then you can get the all invoice increment id by

```
$_invoices = $_order->getInvoiceCollection();
foreach($_invoices as $_invoice){

     $_invoice->getIncrementId() = $_invoice->getIncrementId();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and also this alternative: $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($order->getOrderId()); but it always shows today as creation date and not the real creation date... can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell exactly which place you want to change either front-end or in admin panel

Comment: @user1916533 i have same date problem, how could u solve that?

Comment: me also, can you let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento is creating PDF of orders strictly via PHP code (means it doesn't use any html->pdf parser or any similar idea), you will have to extend the class that does that and modify it accordingly. So, the class that you are looking for is:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
```

with the method

```
protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
```

then search for

```
$page->drawText( Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), 'medium', false), 35, ($top -= 15), 'UTF-8');
```

And I would guess that you know how to extend it with your own module. If not, the process is described in [How to create a simple 'Hello World' module in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento).

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me exactly how to show the invoice date?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and added invoice date to app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/invoice.php at line 132

```
 /* Add document text and number */
        $this->insertDocumentNumber(
            $page,
            Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
 .' '.
        Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice date: ') . Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(
            $invoice->getCreatedAt(), 'medium', false
        ),
        35,
        ($top -= 15),
        'UTF-8'
        );
```