# creating a module helloworld magento

Tags: magento

I followed the tutorial in http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world
but I don't know why the link filipeferminiano.com/lojateste/helloworld does't works.
Here is my config.xml

```
<config>    
<modules>
    <ffdotcom_Helloworld>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ffdotcom_Helloworld>
</modules> <frontend>
    <routers>
        <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>ffdotcom_Helloworld</module>
                <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </helloworld>
    </routers>  
</frontend>
```

Comment: add your controller file to post

Comment: is this your base link? http://filipeferminiano.com/lojateste/
then your controller must be IndexController.php and action name will be indexAction() and extended class Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action

if this all are right in your code add your sample in post.

Comment: Along with the above two recommendations, please post your module declaration file from *app/etc/modules/*

Comment: For those trying to work out if the module is even active, consider the [Module List tool](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/module-list.html).

Comment: I follow the instructions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento and work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create: app/code/local/Ffdotcom/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ffdotcom_Helloworld>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Ffdotcom_Helloworld>    
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ffdotcom_Helloworld</module>
                <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </helloworld>
    </routers>  
  </frontend>
 </config>
```

Create: app/code/local/Ffdotcom/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Ffdotcom_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction(){
        echo 'hello world';
    }

}
```

Create: app/etc/modules/Ffdotcom_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
       <Ffdotcom_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
       </Ffdotcom_Helloworld>
   </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first "f" in your module name *must* be capitalized in the `frontend/routers/helloworld/args` xpath.

Comment: Yes, it is my base link.
My IndexController.php is:

    class Ffdotcom_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {        
    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index!';
    }
}

I already changed ffdotcom to Ffdotcom in all files, but still not works.

Comment: And my module declaration is in a file Ffdotcom_helloworld.xml
With the code:
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ffdotcom_Helloworld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Ffdotcom_Helloworld>
    </modules>
</config>