# Error in Magento when downloaded

Tags: magento

I have recently downloaded a copy of Magento version 1.7.0.2 and upon opening it up in Netbeans there is a red explanation mark on that folder. I have only seen this symbol on my own code to signify that there is an error in the code (i'm doubting this is the case as it Magento).
The files that are displayed as having an error are:

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

I have uninstalled and reinstalled my copy and still have this problem, is this heard of by anyone else? or is it a Netbeans thing?

Also under the folder:

app/code

the only folder there are community and core. In [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento/588683#588683) a local folder is mentioned. Is this something you need to add manually or should it be there on the install?

Comment: Does Netbeans tell you the the specific error, or at least where in the files the error is?

I believe the local folder is only there if you add it - if you haven't written any code yourself, there's nothing that would be in it anyway.

Comment: Yes LINE 234 and 287 of app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/attribute/js.phtml. As for the other two I posted no it doesn't, it just shows  the red explication mark on the folder. I have now found other error icons that I must have missed prior to posting this message

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/config/form/field/array ERRORS on lines 85, 89, 99
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/form/element/themes.phtml ERROR on line 449