# set home page of website with CMS homepage

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I made some changes in cms/pages/homepage. Changes are affected in main index.php file of magento installation. But it is not affected inside website i created inside local folder.

**Questions:**

Why homepage of this website is not set as cms/homepage?
How i can do this ?

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set your home page as per your website or store from admin

just go to

**System -> Configuration -> Web -> Click on Default pages**

set your page what ever you want to set for home page

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: If i created multiple websites in local, how to change it for specific website?

Comment: you can select from left upper drop down for selected website to set your page.if my answer is useful to dont forget to acpt and voteup pls

Comment: I already checked that but it doesn't show me websites i created. It only shows three options 1) Default Config 2) Main Website 3)Main Website Store/Default Store View.

Comment: it doesn't show me my website i created in local. Should i be creating website here ? I followed this tutorial of alan storm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento

Comment: just create new one website and assign store then try

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37568/discussion-between-bsthakrar-and-liyakat)

Comment: Should i create from manage stores or follow the link i posted above ?