# Magento: Adding admin page to 'Admin_Hello' example

Tags: magento, admin

OK, I know this is probably stupid. I have followed Alan Storm's excellent "Admin Hello" tutorial ([How to create a simple 'Hello World' module in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento)), as well as the updated version on his own site (http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited). I have used this as a framework to create a new admin module. But the example does NOT have a front end, ie, a related admin page.

How do I add a new html form that will allow me to collect inputs, and display outputs from my admin module? I have looked at tutorials for creating new blocks, themes, CMS pages, and the like. But none of them seem to address now to create a new admin page, and integrate it with a custom admin module.

Thanks all!  -Don! Briggs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial doesn't follow all of the best practices, but it is an example of what you're looking for.  Even shows you how to implement the grid in admin: http://www.pierrefay.com/create-backend-plugin-magento-75

Comment: This post actually shows some better/additional examples that what I linked to above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359873/create-admin-front-with-a-simple-form-via-a-module-magento