# Create admin front with a simple form via a module [Magento]

Tags: magento

I am pretty new to Magento and am trying to understand how to create admin (backend) page. I have figured how to create/define the controller and action (along with editing the config.xml).

But now the next problem at hand is to display a simple form in that page. I understand that, I have an option to create blocks and mention the blocks in a layout.xml. But from what I figure is that layout.xml needs to be present in the theme folder. Which I can't do as my magento extension will be installed and I have no access to the user's system.

```
So the doubt is. How to display a simple from in a backend (admin) page 
without having to make any changes to the theme's layout ?
```

Comment: use module creator http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html

Comment: Thanks, but hoping to understand the system a little more.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module

Comment: Thanks. Unable to view the page.

Comment: copy from magento.... to _module and paste it in browser.dont know why link broked

Comment: Pasted the entire link in the browser, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For the admin panel module you don't need to mention the block in the layout.xml of your theme, you only need it to be defined in config.xml file in your "app/code/local///etc/" and a layout file is created in "app/design/adminhtml/default/default/".inside the Block create a folder named "Adminhtml" inside it your can create your form. 
Refer this 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module