# How to create a simple 'Hello World' module in Magento? - 404 Error

Tags: php, magento

I'm following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588683/1817530) to stackoverflow question [576908](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576908/1817530) but I seem to be getting a 404 Error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. i.e. beginner mistakes?

IndexController:

```
    <?php
      class MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_IndexController extends         Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "We're echoing just to show that this is what's called, normally you'd have some kind of redirect going on here";
    }
}
```

Config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
 <modules>
    <mycompanyname_helloworld>
        <version>
            0.1.0
        </version>
    </mycompanyname_helloworld>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <!-- the <helloworld> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
        convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
        <helloworld>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>MyCompanyName_HelloWorld</module>
                <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </helloworld>
    </routers>
</frontend>
</config>
```

In app/etc/modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyCompanyName_Helloworld>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </MyCompanyName_Helloworld>
</modules>
</config>
```

I keep geeting a

> 404 Error

when I hit the url 
magento.dev/index.php/helloworld
//NB The url is a virtualhost on my development machine.

[image: A screen shot of the 404]

I'm running magento 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have everything in your config consistently named (e.g. in camel case):

/app/etc/modules/**MyCompanyName_HelloWorld.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>community</codePool>
    </MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
</modules>
</config>
```

/app/code/community/**MyCompanyName/HelloWorld**/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
            <version>
                0.1.0
            </version>
        </MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
    </modules>
...
```

The full call to that would be magento.dev/index.php/helloworld/index/index/.

These should work as well:

```
magento.dev/index.php/helloworld/index/

magento.dev/index.php/helloworld/
```

Got it to work for me that way.

Comment: This should work. Additionally, do not forget to clear cache or disable them :)

Answer (score 0):

Try magento.dev/index.php/helloworld/index
You passed frontName in url, but didn't pass controller name to the url.
BTW, use local code pull for your extensions.

Comment: Statichny, that does not work. Also I'm trying to build a community extension hence according to the magento documentation my code should exist in the community directory