# Why does my custom module give a 404 error when upgrading from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I just downloaded the Magento 1.9.2.1. I followed all the steps as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento) answer and hit `http://127.0.0.1/magentoNew/index.php/helloworld`, which gives 404 although all the files; the code is same (copy pasted).

Also I tried to make another custom module as per [this](http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/comment-page-1/#div-comment-430675) tutorial by Inchoo, but I still get 404 page(One person there has same issue).

I followed all the instructions as per the **Alan Storm's** answer. And it works pretty well on Magento 1.9.1.* pretty well but gives issue on latest version, anyone had and solved the same issue?

**Note: All the files are same in etc, and `local/MyCompanyName/HelloWorld` folder as per tutorial.**

I am using a new PC so I had to install all new setup of Magento 1.9.2.1, so i just copied the same extension files from laptop which used to run there (the laptop has Magento 1.9.1 installed).

[image]

**Edit: As I already wrote, all code you can see here** [How do I create a simple 'Hello World' module in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento), still I write some of the files again.

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mycompanyname_helloworld>
            <version>
                0.1.0
            </version>
        </mycompanyname_helloworld>
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <!-- the <helloworld> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
                convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
                <helloworld>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>MyCompanyName_HelloWorld</module>
                        <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                    </args>
                </helloworld>
            </routers>
        </frontend>

    </modules>
</config>
```

My cache is cleared.

[image]

Comment: Are you using same router for the frontend and the admin?

Comment: I created simple module only for front end.

Comment: Add config.xml code and controller file code in your question.Then  some one might help you.

Comment: Please check config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your config.xml and clear cache and see if it works or not?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mycompanyname_helloworld>
            <version>
                0.1.0
            </version>
        </mycompanyname_helloworld>
    </modules>    <!-- Check this line -->
        <frontend>
            <routers>
                <!-- the <helloworld> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
                convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
                <helloworld>
                    <use>standard</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>MyCompanyName_HelloWorld</module>
                        <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                    </args>
                </helloworld>
            </routers>
        </frontend>    
</config>
```

Comment: check edit. And even after trying your code(moving frontend outside <modules> tag, it say 404, not found!.

Comment: @PratikCJoshi Even if your Magento caches are disabled , you are advised to delete var/cache folder in Magento root. What have you written in your controller code and what is your directory structure for the module?