# Magento dispatch custom event not working

Tags: php, magento, events, design-patterns, observers

I tried the same code from [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-events-in-magento-with-the-observer-pattern--cms-22120) site.

It works well but the code for observer doesnt seem to be working.

I mean in observer method I have echoed some text and used `exit()` too. But the control doesnt go there. I tried to debug a lot, but couldnt get the solution.

Thanks in advance.

This is screen shot of directory structure of my module.

`app/etc/MyCompanyName_HelloWorld.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Now my module files**

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <mycompanyname_helloworld>
            <version>
                0.1.0
            </version>
        </mycompanyname_helloworld>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <!-- the <helloworld> tagname appears to be arbitrary, but by
            convention is should match the frontName tag below-->
            <helloworld>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyCompanyName_HelloWorld</module>
                    <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
                </args>
            </helloworld>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <!--Custom events-->
    <global>
        <events>
            <my_custom_event>
                <observers>
                    <mycompanyname_helloworld_my_custom_event_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>helloworld/observer</class>
                        <method>my_custom_method</method>
                    </mycompanyname_helloworld_my_custom_event_observer>
                </observers>
            </my_custom_event>
        </events>
    </global>
    <!--//Custom events-->
</config>
```

`Observer.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: pratik
 * Date: 9/4/15
 * Time: 7:45 AM
 */
class MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Model_Observer{
    public function my_custom_method($observer){
        $eventName = $observer->getEvent();
        echo "Hi i am inside event".$eventName; exit;
    }
}
```

`IndexController.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: pratik
 * Date: 9/4/15
 * Time: 7:32 AM
 */
class MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "In index controller";
        //Now dispatching event(Sending off the event)
        $arrToObservers = array('cid'=>'123');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('my_custom_event',$arrToObservers);
        ////Now dispatching event(Sending off the event)
        echo "after dispatch";
    }
}
```

**And output I am getting (Without magento executing my observer echo statement)**

`In index controller --after dispatch`

But it was supposed to print `Hi i am inside event` text too written in observer.

[image]

Comment: Your module name should be case sensitive, i.e. `MyCompanyName_HelloWorld` rather than all lowercase in your config.xml

Comment: also the app/etc/ XML file should be `app/etc/modules/MyCompanyName_HelloWorld.xml`

Comment: Robbie sir :) i followed some part from hello world module from here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento . And you cant doubt alan storm's solution !! Have a look there ! :)

Comment: I think you'll find that his answer is a typo rather than being wrong. His first example of talking about that file mentions moving to  `app` then touching `etc/modules/YourModule_Example.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of problems:

1) Change your initialization xml file structure to First Letter CAPS.

```
# File: app/etc/modules/MyCompanyName_HelloWorld.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompanyName_HelloWorld>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2) You're referencing `helloworld/observer` as the model to call on your custom event, but haven't defined the `helloworld` model namespace. Add this to your `config.xml` in the `<global>` block:

```
# File: app/code/local/MyCompanyName/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml:
<global>
    ........Your code ...............
    <models>
        <helloworld>
            <class>MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Model</class>
        </helloworld>
    </models>
    ........Your code ...............
</global>
```

Doing that it now runs as expected (`Recoverable Error: Object of class Varien_Event could not be converted to string  in /path/to/mage/app/code/local/MyCompanyName/HelloWorld/Model/Observer.php on line 11`). If you change the observer method to just output Hello World, it works fine. For example:

```
# File: app/code/local/MyCompanyName/HelloWorld/Model/Observer.php:
<?php                                            
class MyCompanyName_HelloWorld_Model_Observer
{
    public function my_custom_method($observer)
    {
        var_dump('Hello World');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Output: `In index controllerstring(11) "Hello World"`

Comment: Well , I will try that out when I reach home ! +1 in advance :)

Comment: `1) Your XML file in app/etc should be app/etc/modules:` Buddy come on, it was just a typo mistake. I already have it in `app/etc/modules`. And if you read the question properly, I said : I already got some part of extension working except dispatcher. Means Extension is working. If xml file was not in app/etc/modules, extension simply would not have worked at all.

Comment: Glad it worked, but your edit changed the point of the first issue, will adjust shortly