# how to display text in left column using magento

Tags: magento

I am new in magento. I want to display a text present in abc.phtml in left column. I displayed it in center using the given below code:

```
<default>
       <block type="page/html" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/abc.phtml"/>
</default>
```

I wrote the above code on page.xml.

I just wrote simple echo code in abc.phtml

```
<?php
 echo "Welcome to Magento";
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a simple 'Hello World' module in Magento?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576908/how-to-create-a-simple-hello-world-module-in-magento)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your code like this.

```
  <default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="page/html" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/abc.phtml"/>
    </reference>
  </default>
```

Comment: If it help you, please accept it, So it will help other in community as well.